# Actionlib SimpleActionClient Connecting to SimpleActionServer

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to implement a SimpleActionServer and SimpleActionClient, but the client seems to be getting hung up on the "wait_for_server" command.  Both the client and server just sit there producing no messages.

Just so I can get the basic concept down, how exactly do the server and client components get connected?  What class members enable a connection to get established between them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107536/actionlib-simpleactionclient-connecting-to-simpleactionserver/) by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it is only the name of the action and the type of the action, the client and server get templated to.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0